# Passing Json While running python script from terminal

Tags: python, json, shell

I want to pass JSON as a parameter while running the python script from the terminal. Can I pass JSON Object from terminal. However, I can only pass string from the terminal but I need JSON instead of that.

My tried passing string as follows which gave expected result.

```
   $ python test.py 'Param1'
```

But if I want JSON, it gives error.I tried with the following to pass json.

```
   $ python test.py { 'a':1, 'b':2 }
```

Comment: `{ 'a':1, 'b':2 }` isn't valid JSON. But you _could_ pass this is a commandline argument: `'{"a":1, "b":2}'`

Comment: Curly brackets have special meaning to the shell. You need to actually use a string value

Answer (score 1):

Two ways of doing this:

```
$ cat a.py
import json
import sys
print json.loads(sys.stdin.read().strip())
$ python a.py <<< '{ "a":1, "b":2 }'
{u'a': 1, u'b': 2}
$ echo '{ "a":1, "b":2 }' | python a.py
{u'a': 1, u'b': 2}

$ cat c.py
import json
import sys
print json.loads(sys.argv[1])
$ python c.py '{ "a":1, "b":2 }'
{u'a': 1, u'b': 2}
```

Follow up (maintaining order):

```
$ cat d.py
import json
import sys
from collections import OrderedDict
print json.loads(sys.argv[1], object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
$ python d.py '{ "a":1, "b":2, "c":3, "d":4 }'
OrderedDict([(u'a', 1), (u'b', 2), (u'c', 3), (u'd', 4)])
```

Comment: I tried this one. With json having more keys like '{ "a":1, "b":2, "c":3, "d":4 }', I get unordered keys and value pair with json.loads() method. I need a ordered list for json provided in the parameters which I am not getting. Can you help me in this?